# How do I set a purchase limit for my items in Shopify?

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify, liquid

**How do I set a purchase limit for my items?**

I need a way to limit the quantity of items a user could purchase at a time.

We use a quantity dropdown at the cart that match the actual quantity in stock. 
For example, if there are 3 items, the quantity dropdown have a max value of 3. If there are 5 items, then the max value is 5.

The quantity dropdowns maximum is at seven. The problem is that you can still use the add to cart button. How can we disable the add to cart function, if you have reached the max of seven per item variant ?

Shopify store:   http://gloria22x.myshopify.com/products/schnellhefter?variant=791267571

Thanks, Alex

Comment: check here and output it in a javascript http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/line_item#quantity geiler adler